# What horror works are on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Certainly [zombie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie)-related works are on topic, for example [the-walking-dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead).

I presume *The Walking Dead* is on-topic because the zombies are fantastical.   Or if they weren't fantastical, the result of the zombie virus would be considered sci-fi.   Fine.

So do we need to apply one of those criteria to all horror works for them to be on-topic?

For example, is a horror film with a realistic serial killer off-topic?   Or just a deranged individual?   (Like perhaps *Saw*? -- I haven't actually seen it, so I may be wrong here)

Or is horror automatically on-topic regardless of plot or elements?

Comment: I'm fairly sure we decided that there needed to be some level of *fantastical content*. A story about someone who murders other people is not on topic, regardless of their inventiveness.

Comment: @Keen:   I saw that question/answer.   but I don't think it really was really unambiguously decided nor was there any consensus.

Comment: I believe this question is contained by the dupe. For the record, I believe the horror story *must* be fantastical (or science-fictional) in order to be considered here. The realistic serial killer story is *definitely off-topic* here. If it wasn't, then there would be no basis to declare *anything* off-topic here ("I saw a documentary about spiders, and spiders scare me! Can I ask about it here?")